# How can I use IPWorks with a self-signed SSL certificate?

Tags: delphi, ipworks, nsoftware

I am trying to find a way to use [/n Software's IPWorks](https://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/) server/client components with a self-signed SSL certificate.

I am trying this on the client side:

```
cl.SSLCertStoreType := cstPFXFile;
cl.SSLCertStore := 'cert.pfx';
cl.SSLCertStorePassword := 'password';
cl.Connect('localhost',5050);
```

And this on the server side:

```
server.SSLCertStoreType :=  cstPFXFile;
server.SSLCertStore := 'cert.pfx';
server.SSLCertStorePassword := 'password';
server.LocalPort:= 5050;
server.SSLEnabled:=true;
server.Listening := true;
```

The PFX file is valid, but the app gives an error that it's not a valid certificate.

Does somebody have a working example ?

Comment: As per this document on IPWorks site, the self-signed certificate can be generated using CertMgr class provided by same IPWorks library.

https://www.nsoftware.com/kb/xml/11080101.rst

> To generate a certificate, simply call the CreateCertificate method of
> the CertMgr component included in IPWorks SSL. This method takes a
> subject and a serial number as arguments:
> 
> CertMgr1.CreateCertificate "CN=My Cert Subject", 0000001

May be use this certificate instead of any other method..

Not adding this as answer, as not tried yet

Answer (score 0):

As per this document on IPWorks site, the self-signed certificate can be generated using CertMgr class provided by same IPWorks library.

https://www.nsoftware.com/kb/xml/11080101.rst

> To generate a certificate, simply call the CreateCertificate method of
> the CertMgr component included in IPWorks SSL. This method takes a
> subject and a serial number as arguments:
>
> CertMgr1.CreateCertificate "CN=My Cert Subject", 0000001

```
Certmgr certMgr1 = new Certmgr();
certMgr1.RuntimeLicense = ""; //Assign your license, otherwise you'll get exception
certMgr1.CreateCertificate("CN=My Cert Subject", 000001);
//Use certMgr1.Cert property to use generated Self-signed certificate
```